# Chances of Assange extradition?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, extradition

Will the UK extradition decision be highly unlikely?

What are the chances?

Comment: I'm sorry, but we generally don't answer questions which ask us to predict the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a seven year old extradition request from Sweden, which as far as I know is still valid and should have precedence . And traditionally, if you are extradited to a country (like Sweden), you are free to leave anywhere you want to go to once you leave jail or win your court case.

Comment: extradition to the us not sweden is what i meant

Comment: hi. Could sweden then extradite him to usa.